# how to get the URL of a page referrer and load the content in a div using jquery .load

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I have a download page on my WordPress blog.
On this page, I want to grab an HTML element with id="download" from any URL that linked to the download page.

please how do I accomplish this?
look at my code below, but it is not working

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"> </script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var pagereferrer = Document.referrer;
var timeleft = 10;
var downloadTimer = setInterval(function(){
timeleft--;
document.getElementById("countdowntimer").textContent = timeleft;
if(timeleft <= 0)
clearInterval(downloadTimer);
},1000);

$( "#div1" ).load(pagereferrer #download);
</script>
```

```html
<h2>
<span style="font-family: 'comic sans ms', sans-serif;">
<strong>Please wait ! Your download will begin in <span id="countdowntimer">10 </span> Seconds.......</strong>
</span>
</h2>

<div id="div1"> </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help you

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var pagereferrer = Document.referrer;
var timeleft = 10;
var downloadTimer = setInterval(function(){
timeleft--;
document.getElementById("countdowntimer").innerHTML = timeleft;
if(timeleft <= 0)
clearInterval(downloadTimer);
},1000);


jQuery( "#div1" ).load( "pagereferrer #download" );
// or
// jQuery( "#div1" ).load( "ajax/test.html #container" );

</script>
```

Comment: issue is in  jQuery( "#div1" ).load( "pagereferrer #download" );
provide proper .load and it will work for you.

Comment: I think putting the pagereferrer #download inside a "" quote make it not to be recognized as a variable anymore.